# A field or property with the name 'Username' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using a SqlDataSource to bind DetailsView for userprofile, which allows users to view their information and at the same time change their particulars. (select, retrieve and update)

however, this error occured-- A field or property with the name 'Username' was not found on the selected data source when I click the hyperlink to direct to the "userprofile" page.

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A field or property with the name 'Username' was not found on the selected data source.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.   Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the   exception stack trace below.
```

this is the code inside userprofile.aspx file:

```
  <asp:DetailsView ID="UserProfile" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="UserId" 
        DataSourceID="UserProfileDataSource" DefaultMode="Edit" 
        onitemupdated="UserProfile_ItemUpdated">
        <Fields>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                SortExpression="Username" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HomeTown" HeaderText="HomeTown" 
                SortExpression="HomeTown" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HomepageUrl" HeaderText="HomepageUrl" 
                SortExpression="HomepageUrl" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Signature" HeaderText="Signature" 
                SortExpression="Signature" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserProfileDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecurityTutorialsConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserProfiles] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)" 
        onselecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserProfiles SET
        Username = @Username,
        HomeTown = @HomeTown,
        HomepageUrl = @HomepageUrl,
        Signature = @Signature   WHERE UserId = @UserId ">

        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" Type="Object" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="HomeTown" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="HomepageUrl" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Signature" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is the code behind userprofile.aspx.cs :

```
 protected void UserProfileDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

        // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
        e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
    }
```

***EDIT***
I had change the SQL query to:

```
 SelectCommand= "SELECT [aspnet_Membership].UserId, [HomeTown], [HomepageUrl], [Signature] FROM [UserProfiles] INNER JOIN [aspnet_Membership] ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId WHERE aspnet_Membership.UserId=@UserId"
    onselecting="UserProfileDataSource_Selecting"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE UserProfiles SET
    Username = @Username,
    HomeTown = @HomeTown,
    HomepageUrl = @HomepageUrl,
    Signature = @Signature   WHERE UserId = @UserId ">
```

But the error still appear: 
     A field or property with the name 'Username' was not found on the selected data source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the field names in the UserProfiles table. It appears you don't have a Username field. It is good practice to explicitly state the fields you want to SELECT rather than using the `SELECT * FROM ..` syntax.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username"  
                SortExpression="Username" />
```

Comment: was is because the username was a foreign key that's why it triggered to this error? hometown, homepageurl and signature all belong to a same table called "UserProfiles". whereas, username was from the aspnet_membership table that created together with the login control.

Comment: @user1467175 - If you want to display or use data from another table you must JOIN the 2 tables together. Since you don't have the aspnet_membership table as part of your SELECT, you cannot access any of it's data.

Comment: So it should be something like SELECT [m.UserId], [HomeTown], [HomepageUrl], [Signature] FROM [aspnet_Membership m] INNER JOIN [UserProfiles u] ON m.UserId = u.UserId ??

Comment: @user1467175 - Something close to: SELECT m.UserName, u.HomeTown, u.HomepageUrl, u.Signature FROM aspnet_Membership m INNER JOIN UserProfiles u ON m.UserId = u.UserId

Answer (score 1):

Can you try reordering the fields to see if it is only a problem with username? i.e.,

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="HomeTown" HeaderText="HomeTown" 
                SortExpression="HomeTown" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                SortExpression="Username" />
```

If there is a problem with the datasource, you should get the exception on 'HomeTown' now. If you do, one thing to try would be removing the @ from the Parameter assignment:

```
e.Command.Parameters["UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
```

**EDIT**: After seeing your modified SQL, two things:

1. In your SelectCommand, you don't seem to select Username. If `[aspnet_Membership].UserId` is your Username, you can `SELECT  [aspnet_Membership].UserId AS Username`
2. In your UpdateCommand, you are assigning a value to Username even though it does not exist in the UserProfiles table. You need to use a JOIN there as well.

Comment: Hi, the code works well if I didn't add in the username field only after i added in the username field, then this error appeared.

Comment: ok, based on your response to DaveB, it sounds like you have a different problem. I would second the advice to explicitly SELECT the fields you want rather than using the * wildcard. Then your error would have shown up as originating from the SQL statement.